# simple html textarea/contenteditable text editor component supporting links, undo, tab-in/outdent for google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, textarea, contenteditable

im writing a chrome extension and need a simple text editor component so that users can edit **simple notes** in the extension.

required:

- **clickable links**, but without any sort of modal dialog. its sufficient if any "http://.." substrings can be turned into actual clickable links of any sort (ie. divs styled like links and with onclick handler are fine)
- **undo/redo** functionality
- **tab indent/outdent** of a single line or multiple selected lines simultaneously
- **seamless switch** between editing/displaying, ie. no save buttons or reflowing or the like ([counterexample](http://valums.com/files/2009/editableText/demo/demo.htm))
- **dont need** any kind of **formatting** capabilities apart from indenting, just plain text ([counterexample](http://www.freshcode.co.za/plugins/jquery.contenteditable/demo.html))
- html/js that works on **chrome**

i have looked at/tried:

- <textarea/>: undo included and tab indent easy to implement, but no way to do links
- <div contenteditable="true">: undo broken, tab indent=hell (selections and ranges), but links work fine. also have set *white-space: nowrap;* to show indent spaces. this is my current solution but its very buggy, maybe ill have to open another question just for this.
- [tinymce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/): overkill i guess
- [markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/): looks good, but since it is a textarea, i figure no links possible
- [ACE](http://ace.ajax.org/): looks promising, worth a shot? not overkill?
- [kix-standalone](https://github.com/benjamn/kix-standalone) demo doesnt work on chrome (ironically)

any comments or answers very appreciated..

edit: i have used codemirror 1 in my project (Syncpad for Simplenote Chrome extension) and i am quite content with it. CodeMirror provided alot of additional infrastructure for text editing (esp live parsing) which i wouldnt want to miss anymore. Will be updating to codemirror 2 when i have the time

Comment: What's wrong with selections and ranges?

Comment: tried inserting spaces on tab key press at cursor position, partially worked, but was buggy. contenteditable divs are a real drag :/ codemirror is SO much cleaner and better - just perfect!

Comment: It's possible to achieve that without problems in all major browsers. See http://jsfiddle.net/TjUBK/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/)? I don't think it will do links, but it's nicely engineered and you may be able to extend it.

Comment: codemirror fills my listed requirements exactly, and it is already integrated into my extension. thank you very much!

i made links clickable by writing a simple parser that matches "http://.." style tokens. then i wired up the corresponding css class (having cursor: pointer; color: blue;) with a jQuery live('click') event that launches the url in a tab.

Comment: the only thing im missing, and forgot to list as a requirement, is text wrapping. codemirror 2 sadly doesnt support it. i might switch to codemirror 1, which does support it.

Comment: @stephanhattinger: CodeMirror 2 now does text wrapping.